# INSERT INTO with unknown number of column in scriptella

Tags: scriptella

I have to back up a table, which can change number of column. When my etl script starts it doesn't know the number of column. How can I create INSERT INTO table VALUES (?1, ?2, ...) script on the fly?

Regards,
Jacek

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the database, one can use CREATE TABLE FROM SELECT (or similar) to back up the table. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS (SELECT * FROM old_table);
```

Comment: But what if "old_table" and "new_table" should be on the different machines (different databases)? From scriptella point of view on different connection_id?